# Why will the .NET Core CLI ("dotnet") generate a "dll" file aside from an "exe" file?

Tags: .net-core, dll, build, console

I'm trying the "dotnet" command line tool. For example, I can run:

```
dotnet new console
```

This creates a new project, and then

```
dotnet build
```

It will generate *bin/Debug/netcoreapp3.1/XXX.exe* and *bin/Debug/netcoreapp3.1/XXX.dll*.

Why will it generate a DLL file? Is it usable in other cases?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you use the command

```
dotnet new console
```

the generated project file looks like

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.1</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>

</Project>
```

Line

```
<OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
```

specifies that .exe would be generated. This executable simply runs your application which is stored inside the DLL file (the DLL file may be executed directly via `dotnet full_generated_dll_path`). I guess .exe output is convenient in services / daemon scenarios.

The project usually has some dependencies (both managed and unmanaged), so the output contains a lot of DLL files. Looks like there is no reason to merge EXE file and DLL file, because you still have many other DLL files (and application logic should probably also be separated from the way to execute the application).

From the distribution point of view single file which contains all you need to execute the application seems convenient so this feature [was added to](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/whats-new/dotnet-core-3-0#single-file-executables) to .NET Core 3.